# Does $R\circ R=R$ imply that R is a diagonal?

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory

Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal in $A\times A$.

If the relation, R, contains $\Delta \subset R$ and had the property $R\circ R=R$, then $\Delta$ must be R.

#### proof

Because for all $(a,b)$ in the set $A\times A$ where $aRb$ there exists another pair $(b,c)$ such that $bRc$; but because of $R\circ R=R$, $c$ must be equal to $b$ and $b$ must be equal to $a$. Therefore the only values of $A\times A$ that hold true for $R\circ R=R$ are $(\forall x \in A), (x,x)\in R$ or $R=\Delta$.

Does this make sense?
Could someone help me better explain this, or show me a better way of saying this?

Comment: Any reflexive and transitive relation satisfies $R \circ R = R$; and there are plenty of reflexive and transitive relations (also called preorders) that are neither equality nor the "always true" relation.

Comment: It did not make sense to me...

Comment: @DanielSchepler Sorry, I only saw your comment after I posted my answer..

Comment: If $R$ is a relation on $A$ I don't think the "domain" or the "range" of $R$ must equal $A$, so neither transitivity nor symmetry by themselves satisfy the premise of the implication.

Comment: Nevertheless the assertion is false.Consider the example $R=\{(a,a), (b,b), (c,c). (a,b)\}$ on $A=\{a,b,c\}$.

Comment: @StephenMeskin it is not obvious to me that your $R$ is true for $R \circ R = R$.

Comment: cont. $R$ is neither symmetric nor transitive but it satisfies the premises but not the conclusion.

Comment: I think I have a hard time interpreting the composition of relations. Ill go study them.

Comment: Oops, my example is transitive, in fact $R \circ R \subset R$ is equivalent to $R$ is transitive.

Comment: I see now that's your link below.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What might be interesting is conditions on $R$ which do imply that $R=\Delta$. For example, $R=\Delta$ iff 1) $\Delta \subset R$, 2) $R \circ R = R$ and 3) $R$ is *intransitive* where *intransitive* means that transitivity only holds if at least one of the two elements of $R$ in the transitivity statement $\in \Delta $.

Comment: @DanielSchepler See prior comment.

Comment: @Tsangares have you figured out yet that my example satisfies $R\circ R =R$.  In fact, it is implied by $\Delta \subset R$.

Comment: @StephenMeskin Yes this has all been extremely helpful. $R\circ R=R$ is another way of saying transitivity and reflexive is saying $\Delta \subset R$.

Comment: @Tsangares transitivity is equivalent to $R\circ R \subseteq R$ and reflexive added to that gives equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any transitive and reflexive relation will obey $\Delta \subset R$ and $R \circ R = R$. Many are not equal to $\Delta$...

Comment: Cool, this paired with: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386714/proving-that-a-relation-r-is-transitive-iff-r-circ-r-subset-r
Has answered my question. Also thank you Daniel Schelper in the comments.